# Visual Studio and reference paths in sass files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I'm trying to setup a CDN and the only thing preventing me from being successful is referencing external SCSS files within visual studio and web essentials.

for example, local reference works in the .scss file like so:
    `/// <reference path="vars.scss" />`

However, it does not work doing so with an external URL.  `/// <reference path="//cdn.domain.com/vars.scss" />`

Is this possible with Visual Studio 2013?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @cimmanon that's not working for me as I need to be able to access my $variables from the CDN locally.

Comment: Uh huh?  That's the point.  It won't work because you *can't do that*.